# Issues updating a MySQL table using Python's MySQLdb

Tags: python, sql, mysql

I am trying to UPDATE a MySQL table using Python's MySQLdb module. Although the query seems fairly simple it just won't update the information. Here is my code:

```
for username,info in users.iteritems():
  if info[0] > 0 and info[1] > 0:
    month = 8
    year = 2010
    cursor.execute("""
        UPDATE users_disk
        SET
            bytes = %s,
            quota_in_mb = %s
        WHERE
            username = %s AND
            month = %s AND
            year = %s
        """, (info[0], info[1], username, month, year))
    print "Username: %s; Rowcount: %d" % (username, cursor.rowcount)
```

The output looks like this:

```
Username: niu666; Rowcount: 0
Username: antuan; Rowcount: 0
Username: tuyo; Rowcount: 0
Username: angela; Rowcount: 0
Username: felipe; Rowcount: 0
Username: Meni; Rowcount: 0
Username: tronco; Rowcount: 0
Username: queque; Rowcount: 0
Username: cerel; Rowcount: 0
```

Which means none of the rows have been updated! The table has the following contents:

```
mysql> select * from users_disk;
+----+----------+-------+------+---------+-------------+
| id | username | month | year | bytes   | quota_in_mb |
+----+----------+-------+------+---------+-------------+
|  1 | niu666   |     8 | 2010 |   28672 |     1024000 | 
|  2 | antuan   |     8 | 2010 |   77824 |     4608000 | 
|  3 | tuyo     |     8 | 2010 |   28672 |     1024000 | 
|  4 | angela   |     8 | 2010 |   45056 |     2048000 | 
|  5 | felipe   |     8 | 2010 |   53248 |      307200 | 
|  6 | Meni     |     8 | 2010 |   86016 |     4096000 | 
|  7 | tronco   |     8 | 2010 | 3067904 |     1024000 | 
|  8 | queque   |     8 | 2010 |   61440 |     4608000 | 
|  9 | cerel    |     8 | 2010 |  110592 |     5632000 | 
+----+----------+-------+------+---------+-------------+
9 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

And users is a dictionary with the following contents:

```
{'niu666': (28672, 1024000), 'tutk': (-1, -1), 'antuan': (77824, 4608000), 'tolin': (-1, -1), 'tuyo': (28672, 1024000), 'angela': (45056, 2048000), 'felipe': (53248, 307200), 'Meni': (86016, 4096000), 'tronco': (3067904, 1024000), 'queque': (61440, 4608000), 'cerel': (110592, 5632000), 'carok': (-1, -1), 'niu': (-1, -1)}
```

I think the issue might be related to username because if I remove it the update works. But of course I need to use it...

Any pointers/recommendations will be highly appreciated.

Thank you so much,

Unai Rodriguez

-------------------------- update -------------------------

Guys, I am using the following "ugly" workaround... that works:

```
for username,info in users.iteritems():
    if info[0] > 0 and info[1] > 0:
        # The user has positive values, its valid!
        cursor.execute("DELETE FROM " + dbtable + " WHERE username = %s AND month = %s AND year = %s", \
            (username, month, year))
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO " + dbtable + " (id, username, month, year, bytes, quota_in_mb) VALUES (NULL, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)", \
                                            (username, month, year, info[0], info[1]))
```

Still I am interested in knowing what is wrong with the UPDATE (first implementation). I will leave the script like that for now. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 6):

Did you try COMMIT command after update as following?

```
cursor.execute("UPDATE animals SET species=%s WHERE name=%s",('TEST', 'Rollo'))

cursor.connection.commit();
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!!

Still did not work, this is what I tried:

cursor.execute("""
   UPDATE users_disk
   SET
    bytes = %s,
    quota_in_mb = %s
   WHERE
    username = %s AND
    month = %s AND
    year = %s
   """, (info[0], info[1], username, month, year))
  cursor.connection.commit();
  print "Username: %s; Rowcount: %d" % (username, cursor.rowcount)

Comment: @UnaiRodriguez Why is this ';' here in python ?

Answer (score 1):

This answer may be a little late, but for posterity's sake:

After your `cursor.execute( <SQL_HERE> )`, be sure to call `connection.commit()`.

A **proper** method:

```
import MySQLbd
from contextlib import closing

connection = MySQLdb.connect( host="localhost",
                              user="root",
                              passwd="root",
                              db="tableName")

with closing( connection.cursor() ) as cursor:
    try:
        cursor.execute( "SQL UPDATE CODE" )
        connection.commit()
    except:
        connection.rollback()
```

Comment: looks good, but there's a typo on the first line (bd instead of db)

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if `username` in table and `username` from query have same length? If there is any padding (with space character) in table it may not show up in the SQL command prompt and will cause the update to match zero rows.

Also can you pass in the primary key of the table (`id`) along with the `year` and `month` rather than `username`?

Comment: I checked, there are no spaces. Also I do not have the id, I just have the username on the script.

Comment: What I am doing now, which is a bit ugly but works, is deleting the row first then inserting it (instead of the update).

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out that for some reason python doesn't read %s. So use ? instead of %S in you SQL Code.

And finally this worked for me.

```
  cur.execute ("update tablename set columnName = (?) where ID = (?) ",("test4","4"))
```